# Leaflet Search Control - Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: php, laravel, leaflet, geojson, c9.io

I am having an issue with Leaflet Control Search, I am testing on C9.io, using Laravel 5.2, I am trying to search a L.geojson layer but all it comes up with is "Location not Found"
and the console gives error:
"Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

I have a global variables that holds the map, L.geojson layers, and tiles.

```
var map, allcalls, mapquest;

mapquest = new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 18,
    subdomains: ["otile1", "otile2", "otile3", "otile4"],
  });
map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(39.90973623453719, -93.69140625),
    zoom: 3,
    layers: [mapquest]
  });
var promise = $.getJSON("leaflet_php/get_users.php");
promise.then(function(data) {

    allcalls = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
     layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.fn + '<br>' +feature.properties.gender + '<br>' + feature.properties.addr + '<br>'+ feature.properties.city );
 }
    });
    map.fitBounds(allcalls.getBounds(), {
        padding: [20, 20]
    });

    allcalls.addTo(map);
});
```

Then I start the L.control.search, and it shows on the map but when I search I get no results the loader gif never stops and I get console error "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

```
var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: allcalls, 
  position:'topleft',
        propertyName: 'city',
});
  map.addControl( controlSearch );
```

I am generating the json using https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON.  My Json has at least 1000 features, each feature has 30 properties. So this is an abbreviated version. This is a sample of the json I get:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":   {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.191626,26.339826]},"properties":{"id":1,"fn":"SAMUEL","mi":null,"ln":"STANTON","name_pre":"MR","addr":"9 HONEYSUCKLE DR","apt":null,"city":"AMELIA","st":"OH","zip":45102,"z4":9722,"dpc":99,"fips_cty":25,"latitude":26.339826,"longitude":-80.191626,}},
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you instantiate your `L.Control.Search` within your Promise callback?

Comment: No Its not, but their examples do not initiate inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate `L.Control.Search` within your Promise callback, or at least use the [`setLayer()` method](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/src/leaflet-search.js#L152) within that callback.

It looks like you have a [classic asynchronous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call): you initiate an AJAX request (through jQuery's `getJSON`), which will assign the value of your `allcalls` variable once resolved.

In parallel, you instantiate your `L.Control.Search` and specify `allcalls` as the Layer Group to be searched in. However, at that time, the AJAX is still processing (i.e. not resolved), so `allcalls` is still unassigned (i.e. `undefined`).

Therefore your Search Control knows nothing about the `L.geoJson` layer group that is built later on in the AJAX resolution.